# Allow access to groups of users in Eve

Tags: python, rest, acl, eve

I'd like to use Eve (python-eve.org) to write a backend in which

- All data is by default read-write to the user who created it, but invisible to any other user, and
- There are some users who can access (either read-write or read-only) the data created by a specific list of users in addition to their own data.  Each such user has their own list of users whose data they can access.

The first part of that sounds like what Eve calls "User-Restricted Resource Access".  The second part, though, I can't seem to translate to anything in the Eve model.  It's not role-based, it's not groups...

How would one do this?  Is there some general mechanism for adding a hook to check "can user X access document Y" in Eve?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760710/multi-user-restricted-access-with-python-eve

Comment: @AndreyT: Yes, very good hints in that question, although I *think* they were looking at restricting access for each collection and http method, not for each individual document.  So it doesn't exactly answer how to do what I need...